# ASP.NET MVC WindowsAuthentication Users and Roles and RolePermissions stored in DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I wasn't able to get to a post where the scenario what i am working to is accomplished.
1) Need to use **Windows authentication** so went ahead and set the Authentication to Windows in web.config.

2) Now We need to store that user back in DB with all his details like

Email Address and ManagersId ResourcePoolId IsBBEnabled  , LastLogin

3) We need to also Have Permissions for each user

We have one role defined as : Users

4) Users have Permissions instead of Roles, i.e.,

---

User , ObjectName , Create, Update, Read, Delete , Approve,

---

X  ,       Customer,  False, False, True, False, True

Y  ,       Customer,  False, False, True, False, False

---

On the MVC Controller i want to Do some thing like this.

```
[AuthorizeUserFor( ObjectInQuestion ="Customer", PermissionLevel= "Read")]
public class CustomerController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }

    [AuthorizeUserFor( ObjectInQuestion ="Customer", PermissionLevel= "Update")]
    public ActionResult Update()
    {


        return View();
    }
}
```

Is there any article, which could help in getting this? For me this looks like a regular question which most of us would have overcome?

Kind Regards,
Vinay.

Comment: Look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339771/user-and-role-management-mvc4/15340063#15340063). It might help.

Comment: Thank you , couldn't relate that to my needs, I have to use Windows authentication the IPricipal needs to be extended, Permissions instead of roles.